# SQL select command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In sql I have a table like this:

```
empno   |  empname  |  supervisors
------      -------   -------------
1            AAA          NULL           
2            BBBBB          1            
3            CCCCC          2
4            DDDD           3
```

now i want the output like this

```
empno   |  empname  |  supervisors
------      -------   -------------
1            AAA          NULL           (he is the boss, he don't have supervisors)
2            BBBBB        AAA            (the number is replaced by empname)
3            CCCCC        BBBBB
4            DDDD         CCCCC
```

please help me!

Comment: This feels like a homework question...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I noticed you reverted an edit on your post. The community tries very hard to provide constructive edits. If you explain what you did not like, it would be helpful to us all.  Here is an article that may help you understand why `please help me!` was removed. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed

Comment: **WHAT database and which version**?? SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product...

Comment: OP originally tagged as SQL-server-2005 but the tag was removed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT e.empno, e.empName, s.empname
FROM eployee AS e
LEFT JOIN eployee AS s ON e.supervisors = s.empno
```